# Angular 5 [ngForOf] shows only the last record on the loop

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, ng-template

I can make the loop but I do not understand why it only shows me the value of the last record

invoice-list.html

```
<ng-template ngFor let-i [ngForOf]="invoiceService.selectedInvoice.purchases"> 
{{i.product.name | json}}   
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" #pname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="i.product.name" readonly>
</ng-template>
```

[image: htmloutput]

here's an example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jkvzgg?embed=1&file=src/app/components/invoices/invoice-list/invoice-list.component.html) `(login => user:user@user.com | pass: user123)`

how go to this view?
 [image]

Comment: how to go to this view?

Comment: Just click edit button in List invoices

Comment: where is the edit button?

Comment: blue button with edit symbol.

Comment: ok got it there, what is the expected output

Comment: the idea is to show the data that are in the json in the input fields. Look at the result in {{i.product.name | json}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180131/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-rafael-antonio-corzo-gutierrez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use two way binding `NgModel` which binds incoming value to the same variable - `i.product.name`. It doesn't makes much sense to use ngModel here. You export your form with `#invoiceFrom='NgForm` so you can do all validations there. Simply pass a value:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control [value]="i.product.name" readonly>
```